# How to fire an event?

Tags: java, swing

I have the following java code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String filename = args[0];

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image Sample");

    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    f.add(new LoadImageApp(filename));
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

in which a `WindowClosing` event is defined. How can I fire/execute/initiate this event from within my code, leading to the exit of the code?

Additional question: What is this construction I see in the code:

```
new WindowAdapter(){...}
```

i.e. normal brackets followed by curly ones?

Comment: The event is fired by the `JFrame` object and not by you. The answer to the second question is that it is an anonymous class that you can define on the fly as you code.

Comment: The `new WindowAdapter(){...}` is called an anonymous class. First off, the 'normal brackets' are called parentheses. Second, anonymous classses are useful when you just need to override one funciton of a class. Learn moure about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Comment: You could use WindowAdapter wa = new WindowAdapter... and then pass the WindowAdapter object  to the addListener, now you can manipulate the WindowAdapter from outside.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this links  . Hope it helps

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/joshy/archive/2006/02/all_hail_the_pr.html

Also, in this specific case, you don't really need to trigger the event since all it does is call `System.exit(0)`. The only reason you would want to trigger the event within the code by hand is to emulate someone clicking the "X" button to close the window (as opposed to closing the program through other means).

Comment: Not sure why this got upvoted, a PropertyChangeListener doesn't help. A PropertyChangeListener is used to fire PropertyChange events not windowClosing events.

Answer (score 2):

See [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for some general ideas on this topic.

The `ExitAction` shows one way to dispatch the event to the frame. The Action was meant to be used with a JMenuItem or JButton to enable the user to close the frame by other means than clicking on the "X".

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is really no point in simulating the event. Why? Because when the event is fired, it means that something happened in your application, and that is the 'Java' way of telling you: "Hey something happened! Here's the event so you can handle it appropriately.". In your case, it could be the user pressing the X button, or the OS shutting down. What you really want to do here, is to shut down the application, not trigger the event. Consider this:

```
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            ThisClassName.this.shutDown();
        }
    });
//...
}

private void shutDown(){
    System.exit(0);
}
```

This way, you can call shutDown() from wherever you want.

About the parentheses, it's called the Anonymous class. It's a class like any other, it just doesn't have a name. Since JFrame requires a WindowListener as a parameter in it's addWindowListener function, you need to pass it. The thing is, you don't need the WindowAdapter anywhere else in your code, so there is no need to keep a named reference to it.

Comment: `Well, there is really no point in simulating the event.` - I see you didn't read my answer and follow the link. Most application add an `"Exit"` menu item to allow the user to close the application by using the keyboard. Advanced users use the keyboard not the mouse.

Comment: That's not the point. I've been asked this question many times and what beginners don't realise is that what they usually want is to reuse the logic inside the event handler, not to simulate the event. So instead of encapsulating the logic in a function, they try to simulate the click, drag, close or whatever. This answer comes after countless answers to "How do i simulate the JButton click event" (in order to call the logic inside the handler).